# ASP .NET Unable to resolve service for type

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am following an Instructor, everything was going smoothly at first, but after I posted the project to github, there were changes in the files of the project, I think I did something wrong, I edited the content later. But there is a point I missed, I think I can't establish the database connection (or I misunderstand it) I also tried the solutions on the page on this subject, but it didn't work. Could you please help me?

the error I get is as follows

> `System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Repositories.RepositoryContext Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Repositories.RepositoryContext': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet`1[Entities.Models.Product]' while attempting to activate 'Repositories.RepositoryContext'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Repositories.Contracts.IRepositoryManager Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Repositories.RepositoryManager': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet`1[Entities.Models.Product]' while attempting to activate 'Repositories.RepositoryContext'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Repositories.Contracts.IProductRepository Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Repositories.ProductRepository': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet`1[Entities.Models.Product]' while attempting to activate 'Repositories.RepositoryContext'.)

`InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet`1[Entities.Models.Product]' while attempting to activate 'Repositories.RepositoryContext'.
`

I checked my repository layers one by one, I checked my Program.cs links one by one, I checked the instructions on microsoft's site, but I guess I was not able to solve this with my current level of knowledge.

My repositorycontext page looks like this

```
public class RepositoryContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; } 
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; } 


    public RepositoryContext(DbContextOptions<RepositoryContext> options, DbSet<Product> products, DbSet<Category> categories) :
        base(options) 
    {
       
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); 
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
            .HasData(new Product() { Id = 1, ProductName = "Laptop", Price = 1000 },
                new Product() { Id = 2, ProductName = "Keyboard", Price = 500 },
                new Product() { Id = 3, ProductName = "Computer", Price = 2500 },
                new Product() { Id = 4, ProductName = "Monitor", Price = 1000 },
                new Product() { Id = 5, ProductName = "Deck", Price = 500 }
            ); 
        modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
            .HasData(
                new Category() { CategoryId = 1, CategoryName = "Book" },
                new Category() { CategoryId = 2, CategoryName = "Electronic" });
    }
}
```

This is my code at the beginning of the program

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services
    .AddControllersWithViews(); 
builder.Services.AddDbContext<RepositoryContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlite(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString
        ("sqlconnection"), 
        b => b.MigrationsAssembly("StoreApp")); 
});
builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepositoryManager, RepositoryManager>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();


var app = builder.Build();

app.UseStaticFiles(); 
app.UseHttpsRedirection(); 
app.UseRouting(); 


app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"); 

app.Run();
```

and the objects have this shape

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String? ProductName { get; set; } = String.Empty; 
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

```
    public class Category
    {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public String? CategoryName { get; set; }= String.Empty;
        
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not inject `DbSet`'s, just remove them from ctor:

```
public class RepositoryContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; } 
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; } 


    public RepositoryContext(DbContextOptions<RepositoryContext> options) :
        base(options) 
    {
       
    }
    ...
}
```

Or:

```
public class RepositoryContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products => Set<Product>();
    public DbSet<Category> Categories => Set<Category>();


    public RepositoryContext(DbContextOptions<RepositoryContext> options) :
        base(options) 
    {
       
    }
    ...
}
```

To handle nullability warnings if any.

See also:

- [DbContext Lifetime, Configuration, and Initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/)
- [EF Core: Working with Nullable Reference Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/nullable-reference-types)

Comment: Thank you for your solution for this problem, now I have to solve the other problems :)

Answer (score 1):

What need do you have to inject `DbSet<Product>` and `DbSet<Category>` into the constructor? Should work fine without those parameters in the constructor.

Those two arguments could not be constructed and that's what brought about the serivce resolution exception.